# Most efficient, scalable mysql database design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have interesting question about database design:

I come up with following design:

first table:

```
**Survivors:**

Survivor_Id | Name | Strength | Energy
```

second table:

```
**Skills:**

Skill_Id | Name
```

third table:

```
**Survivor_skills:**

Surviror_Id |Skill_Id | Level
```

In first table Survivors there will be many records and will grow from time to time.
In second table will be just few skills which can survivors learn (for example: recoon (higher view range), sniper (better accuracy), ...). Theese skills aren't like strength or energy which all survivors have.
Third table is the most interesting, there survivors and skills join together. Everything will work just fine but I am worried about data duplication.

For example: survivor with id 1 will have 5 skills so first table would look like this:

```
// survivor_id | level_id | level
1 | 1 | 2
1 | 2 | 3
1 | 3 | 1
1 | 4 | 5
1 | 5 | 1
```

First record: survivor with id 1 has skill with id 1 on level 2
Second record ...

Is this proper approach or should I use something different.

Comment: this is a proper approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me. If you are worried about data duplication:

1) your server-side code should be gear to not letting this happen

2) you could check before inserting if it already exists

3) you could use MYSQL: REPLACE INTO - this will replace duplicate rows if configure proerply, or insert new ones (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

4) set a unique index on columns where you want only unique rows, e.g. level_id, level

Answer (score 0):

I concur with the others - this is the proper approach.

However, there is one aspect which hasn't been discussed: the order of columns in the composite key {Surviror_Id, Skill_Id}, which will be governed by the kinds of queries you need to run...

- If you need to find skills of the given survivor, the order needs to be: {Surviror_Id, Skill_Id}.
- If you need to find survivors with the given skill, the order needs to be: {Skill_Id, Surviror_Id}.
- If you need both, you'll need both the key (and the implied index) on {Surviror_Id, Skill_Id} **and** an index on {Skill_Id, Surviror_Id}<sup>1</sup>. Since [InnoDB tables are clustered](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/#.U_kdz_mSw1I), accessing Level through that [secondary index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/secondary-index) requires double-lookup - to avoid that, consider using a [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) index {Skill_Id, Surviror_Id, Level} instead.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Or vice-verse.*